# Display Youtube Views from Url in Label (How to?) VB

Tags: vb.net, youtube

Is it possible to fetch the views from an youtube url to a label in VB?
Searched for hours in google but there is nothing...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Need more info really.  However, you could use the google api https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet, or maybe screenscrape as a couple options

Comment: isn't there a way to do it without api?

Comment: Well, like I said, we really need more info.  What are you trying to do, how are you trying to do it?  I've already suggested you could look at doing some screenscape, but that's not something I would do.  Ask a better question and get better answers

Answer (score 0):

**First Create a ConsoleApplication**

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.Title = "Youtube Fetch Views"
        Dim thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf FetchViews)
        thread.Start()
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Sub FetchViews()
        Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = TryCast(Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MTXs8T7Omg"), Net.HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), Net.HttpWebResponse)
        Dim dataStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        response.Close()
        Dim str As Text.RegularExpressions.Match = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(responseFromServer, "<div class=""watch-view-count"">(.*?)</div>")
        Dim views As String = Str.Groups(1).Value
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
        Console.WriteLine(views)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Exactly a way i'm looking for but doesn't seems to work for me... is there also a way to use this in a form.vb intead of module.vb?

Comment: Yeah you can Edit the Code i hope you know how to do it if now write me an Email codebossleet@gmail.com and send me your Source Code so i can edit it to your needs.